# What are the differences between Catholic and Episcopal saints?

Tags: catholicism, saint

The title says it all, really.  What is the difference between Catholic and Episcopal saints?

Comment: The question assumes there are differences. Is "nothing" an acceptable answer?

Comment: @Andrew Leach St. Thomas More?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a subtle distinction, no doubt. There is a simplified view that Catholics pray **to** saints as intercessors, while Episcopalians pray **about** saints in remembrance. But that's not super accurate.

The Catholic Church bestows the title of Saint upon an individual through a rather lengthy process of **canonization**, after which the individual is officially and formally recognized as a Saint. At least two posthumous miracles are required by the [Congregation for the Causes of Saints](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/csaints/) at The Vatican.

The Episcopal Church (TEC) does not canonize, though she does recognize most of the Catholic Saints by name (one exception I can think of right now is St. Valentine.) Furthermore, TEC includes all baptized Christians in something we call the [Communion of Saints](http://anglican-musings.blogspot.com/2007/06/communion-of-saints.html), believing that everyone has the potential to be an influence to another in faith.